# How can I repair a pothole on the edge of an asphalt driveway?

Tags: driveway, asphalt

I have a large pothole in my asphalt driveway that extends to the edge. I'm considering repairing it with cold patch blacktop, but I'm uncertain of how to deal with the edge. Do I need to add a 2x4 form, or is there a different product I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what's at the edge of your driveway? is it grass? then you might want to brace with a 2x4 against the ground just to keep the edge nice. If you don't want to dig up the ground to put a 2x4 in the ground you could probably get away with a thinner piece of wood.

Comment: The edge of my driveway just runs into a wooded area. Niceness of the edge isn't really the concern so much as holding everything in place while it cures.